# Option.toRight returns Product type. What does it mean?

Tags: scala, either

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706443/using-fold-to-convert-option-to-either-in-scala). It was noted in the comments that the `toRight` returns `Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either`:

```
scala> val ox = Some(0)
ox: Some[Int] = Some(0)

scala> ox.toRight("No number")
res0: Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,Int] = Right(0)
```

Now I wonder how it differs from the `Either` type I need. Should I add `Either[String,Int]` explicitly like that ?

```
scala> ox.toRight("No number"): Either[String, Int]
res1: Either[String,Int] = Right(0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type

```
Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,Int]
```

is just overly-specific because the compiler is able to determine that it's a `Product` and `Serializable`, even though you don't care about those things.  This is just because the compiler always tells you the most specific type it can determine since, naturally, it can't know what level of specificity you want.  But it's telling you that it is `with scala.util.Either[String,Int]`, which is what you want, so you don't need to worry about the extra stuff.  If you want to make the type simpler, then yes, just declare it explicitly.