# Type inference changes in Scala 3

Tags: scala, type-inference, dotty, scala-3

What changes in type inference will Scala 3 bring? <s>Currently documentation simply states [TODO](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/type-inference.html)</s>. For example,

#### [Weak conformance](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/weak-conformance.html)

Scala 2.13

```
scala> val i: Int = 42
val i: Int = 42

scala> val c: Char = 'a'
val c: Char = a

scala> List(i,c)
val res0: List[Int] = List(42, 97)
```

Scala 3 (dotty 0.24.0-RC1)

```
scala> val i: Int = 42
val i: Int = 42

scala> val c: Char = 'a'
val c: Char = a

scala> List(i,c)
val res0: List[AnyVal] = List(42, a)
```

#### Equality

Scala 2.13

```
scala> 42 == Some(42)
          ^
       warning: comparing values of types Int and Some[Int] using `==` will always yield false
val res2: Boolean = false
```

Scala 3

```
scala> 42 == Some(42)
1 |42 == Some(42)
  |^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |Values of types Int and Some[Int] cannot be compared with == or !=
```

Comment: AFAIK, in general improvements, and union types.

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies under inference, but path-dependent types can now be referred to within the same parameter list so less need for AUX pattern.

Comment: @MarioGalic You can watch Guillaume Martres's talks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMvOykNQ4zs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIQjfCKDR5A Slides: http://guillaume.martres.me/talks/typelevel-summit-oslo http://guillaume.martres.me/talks/

Answer (score 5):

So as for your `Equality` example it is actually caused by the new [Multiversal Equality](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/multiversal-equality.html) which pretty much means that if you have an `Eql[A, B]` where A is B then type A can only be compared to things it has an `Eql` instance for them (of the form `Eql[A, C]` or `Eql[C, A]`).

In terms of general type inference for scala 3, the main things are:

- [Union Types](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html): We can now represent union types and expressions like

  ```scala
   if (condition) 1 else "1"
  ```

  should be of inferred as of type `Int | String`.
- [Explicit Nulls](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/explicit-nulls.html): One of the new uses for union types is a way to describe nullable types, so for example we could write such a code in Java:

  ```java
   public String getUser(int id) {
       if (id == 0) {
           return "Admin";
       }
       return null;
   }
  ```

  And also in scala 2 we could write:

  ```scala
  def getUser(id: Int): String = if (id == 0) return "Admin" else null
  ```

  But in scala 3 such a method will also have to be declared as of type `String | Null` to represent its nullability, and will not compile by default in newer versions of scala 3.

  When working with Java it gets more complicated so if you want to know more about it I suggest reading in the link.
- GADT: Similar to how `@functionalInterface` works in java we know have GADTs.
  That means that if you were to have a trait with one unimplemented method:

  ```scala
  trait Fooable {
      def foo(): Unit
  }
  ```

  You could create an instance of it by passing a lambda with that signature, so in this example:

  ```scala
  val fooable: Fooable = () => print("Fooing")
  ```

  There are a few more, including [Context Functions](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/context-functions.html), [Implicit Conversions](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/conversions.html) and [Parameter untupling](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html) but those are the main ones.

Comment: Regarding GADT bulletpoint - `Fooable` seems to be SAM which has been available for a while. How is SAM related to GADT?

Comment: Sorry you are right I meant SAM, sorry for mixing up the names, I actually merged two points by accident.
Relating to GADTs, what I meant to say is that GADT members (specifically of an enum) are inferred to be of the enum's type upon instantiation rather than their actual type.
So for example
```enum Bool{
    case True
    case False
 }
```
would have Bool.True inferred as `Bool` type rather than Bool.True, even though that is its underlying type.

Regarding SAMs is the fact that they now are inferred for java types (no more `new Runnable() { def run() .. }`)

Answer (score 2):

Inferred types are now propagated through the remainder of the single parameter list, which means using multiple parameter lists to aid inference might not be necessary.

Scala 2.13

```
scala> def f[T](i: T, g: T => T) = g(i)
def f[T](i: T, g: T => T): T

scala> f(41, x => x + 1)
             ^
       error: missing parameter type
```

Scala 3

```
scala> def f[T](i: T, g: T => T) = g(i)
def f[T](i: T, g: T => T): T

scala> f(41, x => x + 1)
val res0: Int = 42
```

I guess this change might be related to [Allow inter-parameter dependencies #2079](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/2079)

---

Better inference when type parameters are not surfaced in terms

Scala 2.13

```
scala> def f[F <: List[A], A](as: F) = as
def f[F <: List[A], A](as: F): F

scala> f(List(42))
       ^
       error: inferred type arguments [List[Int],Nothing] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [F <: List[A],A]
             ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : List[Int]
        required: F
```

Scala 3

```
scala> def f[F <: List[A], A](as: F) = as                                                                                                                
def f[F <: List[A], A](as: F): F

scala> f(List(42))                                                                                                                                       
val res0: List[Int] = List(42)
```