# Using polymorphic function as a parameter

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference

I have a function `exec` which accepts 3 parameters and applies a function `f` passed as first argument to the other two - `p1` and `p2`.

```
  def exec[T](f: (T, T) => Boolean, p1: T, p2: T) = f(p1, p2)
```

Everything works fine if I declare in advance a function which will be passed as an argument.

Somehow compiler can infer types for arguments of `eq` or in other words it can figure out that `whatever` in this case is `Int`

```
  // declaring a function with type parameter (polymorphic method)
  def eq[whatever](p1: whatever, p2: whatever) = p1 == p2
  // using a declared function
  println(exec(eq, 10, 10))
```

It also works fine if I explicitly specify `Int` as shown below

```
  // specifying type explicitly in function literal
  println(exec((p1: Int, p2: Int) => p1 == p2, 10, 10))
  // specifying type parameter
  println(exec[Int]((p1, p2) => p1 == p2, 10, 10))
```

**Question 1**

Is it possible to get below working?

```
println(exec((p1, p2) => p1 == p2, 10, 10))
```

For example, by using implicits, defining `exec` differently or using some other way making it possible for compiler to infer types of p1 and p2 so that it does not fail with `missing parameter type`.

So no explicit type hints or declared methods are used.

**Question 2**

How does compiler infer types for `eq` and why it works for expressions like `p1 == p2` or `p1 != p2` but fails for `p1 >= p2` (error is `value >= is not a member of type parameter whatever`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1 Is it possible to get below working?

If you can rewrite `exec` like this:

```
def exec[T](p1: T, p2: T)(f: (T, T) => Boolean) = f(p1, p2)
```

Then, the compiler will already know the input type of the function.
So, you will be able to call it like this:

```
println(exec(10, 10) { case (p1, p2) => p1 == p2 })
```

This is a common idiom, to put plain parameters first and then a function on a single parameter group.

> How does compiler infer types for eq and why it works for expressions like p1 == p2 or p1 != p2 but fails for p1 >= p2

Because, **Scala** has *universal equality* (which is one of the things people most criticize of the language, but it was necessary for **Java** interop).

So, you can always compare two objects of any class for equality.
That is because equality is defined in the **Any** superclass as follows.

```
class Any {
  def equals(other: Any): Boolean
}
```

But, ordering is not universal.
If you want, you may want to write a generic function which works for any type as long as there is an order for such type, you may be interested in the [`Ordering`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html) - [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html).
But that is topic for another question.

Comment: Thanks! One minor addition - there is no need in anonymous partial function. It works like this as well `println(exec(10, 10)((p1, p2) => p1 == p2))`.

Comment: Quick description why currying is needed in Scala 2 in such cases for type derivation - https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html

Answer (score 3):

Scala 3 (dotty) will be able to infer the types in `exec` without having to rely on multiple parameter lists to help inference

```
scala> def exec[T](f: (T, T) => Boolean, p1: T, p2: T) = f(p1, p2)
     | exec((p1, p2) => p1 == p2, 10, 10)
def exec[T](f: (T, T) => Boolean, p1: T, p2: T): Boolean
val res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Remember my comment the other day saying _"improvements in general"_, well here you have one :p

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Consider adding it as an answer there. It would make a great example.

Comment: I believe the best for that answer would be to make it a community answer and you may keep adding examples as you found them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez https://stackoverflow.com/a/62184556/5205022