# Using operator (or synthetic function) as a parameter

Tags: scala, operators, comparison-operators

Below code works fine

```
  def exec(f: (Int, Int) => Boolean, p1: Int, p2: Int) = f(p1, p2)
  val >= = (x1: Int, x2: Int) => x1 >= x2
  println(exec(>=, 10, 10))
```

however the question is, if it's possible to get it working without explicit re-defining operator (synthetic function)?

**Update**

It's clear that it works absolutely fine like this

```
println(exec(_ >= _, 10, 10))
```

The question is whether it's possible to make it working in a form `exec(>=, 10, 10)` without defining functional value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer my own question.

Comparison methods are declared in `Int` in a following way

```
def>=(x: Int): Boolean
```

So they are called for an instance of `Int` and applied to one argument.
There is no way to pass such methods as parameters without "binding" them with two arguments.

We can do this by declaring method or functional value in advance and map it to `>=` method in `Int` like below

```
def >= (x1: Int, x2: Int) = x1 >= x2
def >= = (_: Int) >= (_: Int)
val >= = (x1: Int, x2: Int) => x1 >= x2
val >= = (_: Int) >= (_: Int)
```

or by using anonymous function in a form `_ >= _`.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62124166/4111404) you may do this:

```
println(exec(10, 10)(_ >= _))
```

Comment: As shown in your other answer currying helps to infer parameters' type in Scala 2 (Scala 3 can do that without multiple parameter lists). I do not think currying makes any difference here. Question is more about whether there is any way to omit placeholders (underscores).

Comment: @DrYWit yeah AFAIK, there is no way to transform the symbolic method to a function without an alias or the place holder.