# elegant way of extracting option value when need it

Tags: scala

I have an object that had an optional field on it, and on certain point of my code I need to have this field, so I did something like this:

```
  def updateReport(task: Task): Future[Task] = for {
      taskResponse <- Future {
        task.response.getOrElse(throw NoExpectedFieldsException(s"expected to have Response for taskId: ${task.taskId}"))
      }
      res <- reportService.updateReportWithResponse(taskResponse) map (_ => task)
    } yield res
```

task looks something like:

```
Task(taskId: String, ... , response: Option[Response])
```

is there a more elegant way of doing that?

thought maybe to add function:

```
  private def extractOpt[T](elem: Option[T]) = {
    elem.getOrElse(throw NoExpectedFieldsException(s"expected to have element"))
  }
```

but that just moves the ugliness somewhere else...

Task is a case class I created to be able to create differet type of tasks, it has a field called taskType that determain which type of task it is, and all the required elements are on the task as options

Comment: When `task.response` would be `None`. Since it is modeled to have option here in some cases it happens.

Comment: The idea of an **Option** is that the field may or may not exists. If at some point you are _"sure"_ it exists, then it means that either you have a model error or that your assumptions are not 100% accurate and some day they will fail. Anyways, what did you expect with an elegant solution?

Comment: What about flatMap? Then you get your result or a None?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I created it as an option since I wanted the model Task to be used for different type of tasks with field that called taskType, so you could have different type of tasks and all the elements that are possible for the different type of tasks are optiones. I think its pretty common way of doing something like this, i have seen it around before

Comment: @user804968 seems like a pretty common way of doing things in **Java**. What you probably should do is make `Task` a `sealed trait` and create different case classes for each kind of task, where each only has the valid fields for that task. Where you need to be generic you can use pattern matching or define only common fields in the trait, and when you need a specific kind of task you ask precisely for that one, that way you do not have to _unwrap_ fields that will never be none.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez even if i created a specific task, a task that have response is something that is created and being sent to another server, and he sends the response and then I populate the task with the response. so the response again will have to be an option untill i get back an answer from the server and update the response

Comment: @user804968 you use a different class for making the request and modeling the response. The one returned after the response has that field as a non-optional field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Option` forms a monad so we can map over it

```
def updateReport(task: Task): Future[Task] = {
  task.response.map { taskResponse =>
    reportService.updateReportWithResponse(taskResponse).map(_ => task)
  }.getOrElse(Future.failed(new NoExpectedFieldsException(s"expected to have Response for taskId: ${task.taskId}")))
}
```

`Option` is an algebraic data type so we can pattern match on it

```
def updateReport(task: Task): Future[Task] = {
  task.response match {
    case None => 
      Future.failed(new NoExpectedFieldsException(s"expected to have Response for taskId: ${task.taskId}"))
      
    case Some(taskResponse) => 
      reportService.updateReportWithResponse(taskResponse).map(_ => task)
  }
}
```

`Option` can also be folded to a pure value, as Luis suggests,

```
def updateReport(task: Task): Future[Task] = {
  task.response.fold(
    Future.failed[Task](new NoExpectedFieldsException(s"expected to have Response for taskId: ${task.taskId}"))
  ) { taskResponse =>
    reportService.updateReportWithResponse(taskResponse).map(_ => task)
  }
}
```

`Option` can represent a non-existent value, and for that purpose extracting pure value out of it is an unsafe operation so it is probably a good idea to have unsafe operations appear uglier in code to discourage or make visible their use

```
task.response.getOrElse(throw NoExpectedFieldsException(s"expected to have Response for taskId: ${task.taskId}"))
```

Comment: `map` + `getOrElse` = `fold`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Is there a general name for a structure that provides `fold`?

Comment: You mean like `Functor`? There is probably one, but I do not know which one. However, `folds` - However, `folding` means take an **ADT** and one function for each case of the **ADT** and return a plain value. Take a look to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cS4MOUsuWYc). - I know the more concrete `foldLeft` and `foldRight` variants for collection-like effects are modeled by  `Foldable`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for the additional suggestion

Comment: @MarioGalic why in the first example you dont need to specify the case class of the ```Future.faild``` but in the fold case you have to ```Future.failed[Task]```?

Comment: @user804968 Because of the way type inference works in Scala 2 for multiple parameter lists in signatures such as `Option#fold`. Because `Future.failed(new NoExpectedFieldsException(...)` infers to `Future[Nothing]` in first parameter lists, this constraint is enforced in second parameter lists as well. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63021464/5205022